# retrieving facebook token expiry from ACAccountStore/ACAccount?

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6

Is there any way to tell when your facebook token is going to expire when using `ACAccountStore` and `ACAccount`?

I create an `ACAccountStore`, get access to the user's facebook account, store the account in an `ACAccount` object, and am able to retrieve the token from the credentials. I'd also like to be able to know when this token is going to expire though. How would I go about pulling the expiry for this token? Or is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to know when it's going to expire?

When you get a token, in Facebook's case, it's token lifetime is extended. I think today this is for an extra 60 days. So when you get it from the accounts store, it should be good to go.

The only detail you should be concerned about it if the user is using your app, and then decides to revoke permissions from the Facebook settings itself.

In this case you need to make sure you're monitoring the `ACAccountStoreDidChangeNotification` notification and call `renewCredentialsForAccount:completion:` appropriately to ask for permissions again, see [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accounts/Reference/ACAccountStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ACAccountStore/renewCredentialsForAccount%3acompletion%3a).

For example:

```
- (void)accountChanged:(NSNotification *)note
{
    [self.accountStore renewCredentialsForAccount:(ACAccount *)self.facebookAccount completion:^(ACAccountCredentialRenewResult renewResult, NSError *error){
        if(!error)
        {
            switch (renewResult) {
                case ACAccountCredentialRenewResultRenewed:
                    // Good
                    break;
                case ACAccountCredentialRenewResultRejected:
                    // Maybe go back to non logged in status
                    break;
                case ACAccountCredentialRenewResultFailed:
                    // Maybe internet failed, Facebook is down?
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }
        else{
            // Handle error gracefully
        }
    }];
}
```

Maybe [this tutorial](http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/eric-stroh/ios-6-tutorial-integrating-facebook-your-applications) may be of some help for you.

Comment: I don't actually need the information for anything I'm using it. An API I'm working with requires it along with the session token.
Really appreciate the tutorial though, will be helpful.

Comment: FYI, for those who can't find the above-linked tutorial ("Not Found"), it looks like the URL has moved here:

https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/ios-6-turorial-integrating-facebook-into-your-applications